# How can I get browser screen resolution on asp.net mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing responsive web application in the asp.net mvc.
I want to set some product boxes based on the Current browser/screen resolution, but i am getting issue in getting the correct width of browser resolution.
If I write `Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth` it gives me all time 640*480.
But its wrong. And if I write the `var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
                var width = screen.Width;`

Its giving me correct windows resolution which i have set from my window property. Its giving me 1600*900 which is correct value. But issue here is if i manually make my browser screen small and run again that code at that it also gives me 1600*900, but it should give me the size of what i have done manually small.

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried on client side?

Answer (score 1):

Handling browser size on the server, you won't know if the user resizes the browser between requests. The correct way to handle browser size is on the client with CSS media queries. Media queries allow you to dynamically set different styles for different browser sizes, i.e. a more responsive layout. Here's a decent intro:

http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/